# How to use Spatial Type in Grails4 / GORM7?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, spatial

How can I model spatial type property in GORM7 and how can I query these spatial properties like other ordinary types such as String/Date/Number etc.

The [Hibernate support spatial types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#spatial) by introducing specific dialect and classes such as "MySQLSpatialDialect" and "com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point".

I found some [plugins](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-spatial) for grails-v1/v2, but it is not for grails4.

If I have to write a plugin to do this, how can I start it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all inside the box, but you need to configure it a bit!

Create your definition table. Note, that if you auto-create, mysql might not choose correct datatype for the location.

```sql
create table book (id bigint auto_increment primary key, version bigint, title varchar(255), location point)
```

In your application.yml, you need to add the correct dialect:

```yaml
dataSource:
    dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect
    ...etc
```

To your build.gradle (note, vividsolutions changed name to locationtech):

```gradle
    compile "org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.18.1"
    runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:5.5.2.Final"
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18'
```

Create a domain class with a geometry field:

```groovy
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point
class Book {

  String title 
  Point location

}
```

Create service for your books:

```groovy
import grails.gorm.services.Service
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point
@Service(Book)
interface BookService {
    Book save(String title, Point location)
}
```

Create some dummy data:

```groovy
import org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTReader
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point

Book book = bookService.save('Test', (Point)new WKTReader().read("POINT (0 1)"))
```

To test your book location against some polygon:

```groovy
import org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTReader

class Controller {

    def sessionFactory

    @ReadOnly
    def index() {
        
    def q = new WKTReader()
    def filter = q.read('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))')

    def session2 = sessionFactory.currentSession
    def queryParams = [:]
    queryParams.loc = filter

    List<Book> results = new ArrayList<>()
   
    def query =
    """
    select b from Book b 
    where st_within(b.location, :loc) = true  
    """

    results = Book.executeQuery(query, queryParams)
    println(results)
    }

}
```